# Transform MVC3 (Razor) form to Ajax form

Tags: ajax, forms, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have an MVC3 Razor form in index.cshtml using `HtmlHelper`. It works, but I want to replace it with Ajax form using `AjaxHelper` (note: I am still not familiar to Ajax/jQuery). It fails. My questions:

1. What's wrong with my code?
2. Are there any good websites that explain this kind of transformation?
3. If one transforms a view to Ajax processing, is it necessary to change the controller as well?

Here's my index.cshtml file. My trial with Ajax is commented out below the MVC3 form.

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

@using ( Html.BeginForm("UploadFile", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new
{
    enctype = "multipart/form-data"
}) )
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Select a file</legend>
        <input type="file" id="fileupload" name="fileuploadname" />
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Upload" id="upload" onclick="javascript:document.getElementById('upload').disabled=true; document.getElementById('upload').value='Uploading...'" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}

@* @using ( Ajax.BeginForm("UploadFile", "Home",
                new AjaxOptions
                {
                    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
                    HttpMethod = "POST"
                }) )
{
    <input type="file" id="fileupload" name="fileuploadname" />
    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Upload" id="upload" onclick="javascript:document.getElementById('upload').disabled=true; document.getElementById('upload').value='Uploading...'" />
    </p>
}
*@
```

Thx in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't upload files using Ajax. At least not directly.

There are of course [few plugins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166221/how-can-i-upload-files-asynchronously-with-jquery/204271#204271) that help you with this, but they qork outside of `AjaxHelper` scope. This simply means you will have to *get your hands dirty with jQuery* which is also a good thing. It's a simple and small library and while getting acquainted with it you'll most likely deviate away from `AjaxHelper` and rather just use jQuery (with `HtmlHelper`).